# Why does my text field get hex encoded when storing a string to postgresql with SQLAlchemy in Python 3

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

This one has had me stumped for a while now.  I have a column in a postgresql database that I have declared as text.  In my web app, I'm storing to this column using a SQLAlchemy like this:

```
engine = create_engine(dburl, client_encoding='utf8', convert_unicode=True)
questions = Table('questions', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
questions.update().where(
    questions.c.id == res['id']).values(question = self.block_text.encode('utf8'), 
    timestamp=last_changed, is_private='F'...)
```

The `block_text` value is a python3 string.

Here's what it looks like when it gets to the database:

```
\x0a3c6469...
\x0a3c6469...
\x0a3c6469...
```

When I get them back using a query I have to check for the `\x` at the start of the string and then `foo[2:].decode('hex')` to recover the readable string value.  Which works nearly all the time, but I don't understand why this is happening.  The same code when run under Python2 stores the string in readable format. What do I need to do to get the string stored in a readable format in Python3 ??

Comment: If you have a `unicode` object (`block_test`), and you've configured everything to expect `unicode` objects, why would you then encode it into UTF-8 before you send it to the DB?

Comment: I'm grasping at straws here trying to make it work.  I know that it is redundant, but I'm just trying everything.

Comment: No, it is not simply redundant. It is the source of your bug.

Comment: Thank you, that was stupid of me, and explains the difference between 2.7 and 3.x